# Easy way of loading project's Rebar dependencies in Erlang shell

Tags: erlang, rebar

I've got a project that uses Rebar as build tool. When developing, I would like all my app dependencies that are specified in Rebar.config be compiled & loaded in the shell as easy as possible. I'm using the Erlang shell in Emacs. What's a quick way to do this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm not using Emacs so I may miss the Emacs-specific side of your question, but when I want an Erlang shell with all my rebar dependencies loaded, I use:

```
erl -pa ebin deps/*/ebin
```

Comment: The second `-pa` isn't needed: `erl -pa ebin deps/*/ebin` also works. I suppose you could alias that if you want even fewer characters to type.

Comment: I recommend using -pz instead of -pa.  In case you ever have a module named lists.erl or gen_server.erl ... or one of your dependencies has such a module ... you can avoid mistaking your module with OTP's.  :-)

Comment: Tnx for you answers. With what command can I now load all the modules inside the ebin and deps dir and start executing them in the shell?

Comment: Created a seperate question for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6923491/load-all-erlang-modules-in-path

Answer (score 7):

```
./rebar shell
```

should load all your dependencies.