# How to load all Erlang modules in a directory automatically?

Tags: module, erlang, erl

Using the answer from [Easy way of loading projects with rebar dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913523/easy-way-of-loading-projects-rebar-dependencies-in-erlang-shell/6916701#6916701), dependencies are now automatically resolved, but they are not automatically loaded.

So, how can I load all the modules in my ebin and /deps/*/bin path automatically? That way they are available when using the Erlang shell tab completion, which speeds up my dev process considerably.

**My solution based on the great answer of Adam Lindberg**: https://gist.github.com/1131312 It will only load the project modules automagically, so almost no delay in erl startup.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This snippet would do the trick:

```
[code:ensure_loaded(list_to_atom(filename:rootname(filename:basename(F))))
 || P <- code:get_path(), F <- filelib:wildcard(P ++ "/*.beam")].
```

Put it in your `~/.erlang` file as one row (including the dot: `.`) and it will be executed upon starting *any* Erlang shell. Be warned though, it's hideously slow!

```
» time erl -noshell -s init stop
erl -noshell -s init stop  0.11s user 0.02s system 11% cpu 1.143 total # Without
» time erl -noshell -s init stop
erl -noshell -s init stop  7.31s user 1.08s system 88% cpu 9.480 total # With
```

Comment: Tnx, I'm happy to trade in some upfront performance for convenience.

Comment: Yeah, auto-loading of the module upon the first TAB press would be cool. :-)

Answer (score 6):

if you spawn the process, you will get a very fast start.

```
LP = fun() -> [code:ensure_loaded(list_to_atom(filename:rootname(filename:basename(F)))) || P <- code:get_path(), F <- filelib:wildcard(P ++ "/*.beam")] end.
spawn(LP).
```

in the ~/.erlang file

Comment: @VansS To make sure the shell can autocomplete module and function names when pressing Tab.

Comment: @Adam Lindberg  Right. In the scope of this particular question using ensure_loaded this way makes sense.